# My return value is nil and I don't know why(Swift)

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, return-value

```
func getUsername() -> String {
    var username: String!

     Firestore.firestore().collection("UserData").document("\(userID!)").getDocument { (document, err) in if let document = document, document.exists {
         let data = document.data()
         username = data!["username"] as? String
    
        }
    }
    return username
}

func getUsername() -> String { 
var username: String! Firestore.firestore().collection("UserData").document(" 
 (userID!)").getDocument { (document, err) in if let document = document, 
document.exists { let data = document.data() username = data!["username"] as String 
return username 
} 
} 
}
```

It is saying that username is **nil**. It appears its returning before fetching the data, how do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure user is there in `Firestore` database?

Comment: Yes, there is, when I put a fake value in the return such as "user1" and I print out the username it says the correct username. So it is definitely in the database. It seems like it just returns right away.

Comment: This is Async call where you need to wait for the data from server so definitely  `return username` will return `nil`. if you put it inside your `Firestore` call it should return a correct data

Comment: And you can use closures in this case.

Comment: I tried that and an error appears which says "Unexpected non-void return value in void function"

Comment: Please share a code.

Comment: func getUsername() -> String {
        var username: String!
 
     Firestore.firestore().collection("UserData").document("\(userID!)").getDocument { (document, err) in if let document = document, document.exists {
         let data = document.data()
         username = data!["username"] as? String
        
        return username
        
        }
        }
            
    }

Comment: Please add it in your question.

Comment: An error appears which says "Unexpected non-void return value in void function"

Comment: Please read the duplicate. You cannot return something from a method which retrieves data asynchronously.

Comment: Ok, so then how do I solve this problem when I do not return in the async method?

Comment: Once again, read the duplicate especially the **Solution** in the answer. You have to add a completion handler.

Comment: @bikicodes try this example when I have used `completionHandler`
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Gvfwt4Nv8J/

Comment: Link updated. Please check new once @bikicodes

Comment: Perfect now it works thank you very much. The duplicate also helped as well.